# Does Cubert have a clone-day?

Tags: futurama, episode-identification

I'm sure at some point I've seen an episode of Futurama where they celebrate Cubert's cloning day, or his sample taking day? I've searched on two separate occasions to find the reference but I can't.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging, I [found](http://theinfosphere.org/Birthday#Appearances_2) it.  His Growth-Scraping Day is celebrated in [Bender Should Not Be Allowed on Television](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender_Should_Not_Be_Allowed_on_Television).

Comment: YES! Thanks you so much!

Comment: @keen, you had to do digging? For shame... Had I only seen this sooner.

Comment: @DampeS8N I readily admit that my Futurama knowledge is rusty.  It's part of why I'm rewatching it.

Comment: @Keen Rewatching? I fall asleep to the show every night, and have for the last 4 years.

Comment: @DampeS8N Only 4 years?  What've you been doing for the 8 before that?!

Comment: @Keen living without a DVD player in my bedroom. Before that I watched it basically every day, including multi-year-old tivo recordings I had before getting said DVDs. And before that it was on adult swim, and before that as it aired. And then it was before the show started. And then I don't know what.